# A more general function for the number of matching elements among the n elements of a list

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the number of common entries among the elements of a list:

```
temp<-list(element1=c("a","b","c"), element2=c("b","c","d"), 
           element3=c("d","e","f"), element4=c("a","c","z"))
```

To get the overlap among all pairwise combinations of the elements, this function works:

```
calculate.overlap.2<-function(y){
  pw<-combn(y,2,FUN=function(x)sum(x[[1]]%in%x[[2]]))
  names(pw)<-combn(y,2,FUN=function(x)paste(names(x)[[1]],names(x)[[2]],sep="-"))
  return(pw)
}
```

To get the overlap among all three-way combinations of the elements, this function works:

```
calculate.overlap.3<-function(y){
   pw<-combn(y,3,FUN=function(x)sum(x[[1]]%in%x[[2]]&x[[1]]%in%x[[3]]))
   names(pw)<-combn(y,3,FUN=function(x) paste(names(x)[[1]],names(x)[[2]],names(x)[[3]],sep="-"))
   return(pw)
}
```

but as you can tell from the numbers inside the function, this is not an elegant solution.

It would be really nice to generalize these two functions into one, and have a function takes as an input the elements in each check of overlap.  That is, an input of  `number.of.elements.per.comparison=2` would be equivalent to `calculate.overlap.2` above and an input to the function of `number.of.elements.per.comparison=3` would be the same as `calculate.overlap.3`.

I feel like there is a very elegant solution to this, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
calculate.overlap <- function(y, i){
  pw <- combn(seq_along(y), i, FUN= function(x) {
    res <- length(Reduce(intersect, y[x]))
    names(res) <- paste(names(y[x]), collapse = "-")
    res
  }, simplify = FALSE)
  do.call(c, pw)
}

calculate.overlap(temp, 3)
#element1-element2-element3 element1-element2-element4 element1-element3-element4 element2-element3-element4 
#                         0                          1                          0                          0
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach:

```
ix = lapply(seq_along(temp), function(u) combn(seq_along(temp), u))

lapply(ix, function(m){
    res = apply(m,2, function(v) length(Reduce(intersect, temp[v])))
    setNames(res, apply(m, 2, paste, collapse='-'))
})

#[[1]]
#1 2 3 4 
#3 3 3 3 

#[[2]]
#1-2 1-3 1-4 2-3 2-4 3-4 
#  2   0   2   1   1   0 

#[[3]]
#1-2-3 1-2-4 1-3-4 2-3-4 
#    0     1     0     0 

#[[4]]
#1-2-3-4 
#      0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the package `VennDiagram` there's a function called `calculate.overlap` which does exactly that. You can even consult the list and see which elements are in each intersection if you need to see them. You can do overlaps of a list with up to 5 sub-lists.

link to package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/index.html

Comment: Have you looked at the code in that function?  Roland's solution is much better.

Comment: Only if ALL he wants is the NUMBER of common entries. If, by any means, he wants to know which entries are in each intersection, he can't. 'calculate.overlap' function from 'VennDiagram' package gives that. So does 'venn(x) - attr(x, "intersections")' from 'gplots' package.